# OR Tools SCIP solver does not use restrictions

Tags: or-tools

I have working example with little data frame:

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import pandas as pd
import json

def main():
    # Data
    priority = [
    [30,    20, 10, 10],
    [10,    20, 30, 40],
    [40,    30, 20, 10],
    [30,    20, 10, 10],
    [30,    20, 10, 10],
    [10,    20, 30, 40],
    [20,    20, 10, 10],
    [40,    20, 30, 40],
    [10,    30, 20, 20],
    [10,    40, 20, 10],
    [30,    20, 10, 99],
    [10,    15, 30, 40],
    ]

    field_area = [30,50,100,20,40,30,130,150,110,29,410,320]

    crop_limit = [110,1121,120,140]

    num_crops   = len(priority)
    num_fields   = len(priority[0])
    num_area = len(field_area)
    num_limit = len(crop_limit)
    print ('Fields',   num_crops)
    print ('Crops' , num_fields)
    print ('Area', num_crops)
    print ('Constraints', num_limit)

#team1 = [0, 2, 4]
#team2 = [1, 3, 5]
# Maximum total of tasks for any team
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] is an array of 0-1 variables, which will be 1
    # if worker i is assigned to task j.
    x = {}
    for i in range(num_crops):
        for j in range(num_fields):
            x[i, j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, '')

    # Constraints
    # One field - one crop
    for i in range(num_crops):
        solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for j in range(num_fields)]) == 1)

    # Only 2 field for crop (only for testing)
   # for j in range(num_fields):
   #     solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for i in range(num_crops)]) <= 2)

    # Area constraints
    for j in range(num_fields):
      for i in range(num_crops):
        solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j]] *  field_area[i]) <= crop_limit[j])    

    # Objective
    objective_terms = []
    for i in range(num_crops):
        for j in range(num_fields):
            objective_terms.append(priority[i][j] * x[i, j])
            solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(objective_terms))

    # Solve
    status = solver.Solve()

    # Print solution.
    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL or status == pywraplp.Solver.FEASIBLE:
        print(f'Total optimum = {solver.Objective().Value()}\n')
        for i in range(num_crops):
            for j in range(num_fields):
                # Test if x[i,j] is 1 (with tolerance for floating point arithmetic).
                if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0.5:
                    print(f'Field {i} Crop {j}.' +
                          f' Priority: {priority[i][j]}' + f' Area: {field_area[i]}' + f' From limit: {crop_limit[j]}' )
    else:
        print('Task doesent have decision.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

But if i use more data (from json file [FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FuySUOES71c5F0_58MZ2QDWxRe5k-8mq/view?usp=sharing)), the result of the algorithm does not meet the constraints. The total amount of area by crop exceeds the limit.

Code for file is here:

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('..........SPP_DATA_v4.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
  field_area = data['fld_area']
  crop_limit = data['crop_goal'] 
  priority = data['spp_lines'] 
  num_fields    = len(priority)
  num_crops   = len(priority[0])
  num_area = len(field_area)
  num_limit = len(crop_limit)
  print ('Field',  num_fields )
  print ('Crops' ,num_crops )
  print ('Constraints', num_limit)

  solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
  #solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('CPLEX_LP')

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] is an array of 0-1 variables, which will be 1
    # if worker i is assigned to task j.
  x = {}
  for i in range(num_fields):
      for j in range(num_crops):
          x[i, j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, '')

    # Constraints
    # one field - one crop
  for i in range(num_fields):
     solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for j in range(num_crops)]) == 1)

    # Maximum area constr
  for j in range(num_crops):
    for i in range(num_fields):
      solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j]] *  field_area[i]) <= crop_limit[j])
    #   solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j]] *  field_area[i]) <= 5000)
    #   print('Added constraint for crop ', j ,crop_limit[j])
    # Constraint for area percent
  #for j in range(num_fields):
    #for i in range(num_crops):
     #  solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j]] *  field_area[i]) >= (crop_limit[j] * 0.1))          

    # Objective
  objective_terms = []
  for i in range(num_fields):
    #print(i, range(num_crops))
    for j in range(num_crops) :
        #print(j, priority[i][j])
        objective_terms.append(priority[i][j] * x[i, j])
        solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(objective_terms))

    # Solve
  status = solver.Solve()

    # Print solution.
  print(status)  
  if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL or status == pywraplp.Solver.FEASIBLE:
    print(f'Total optimum = {solver.Objective().Value()}\n')
    result_arr = []
    jsondata = {}
    result = {}
    for i in range(num_fields):
       for j in range(num_crops):
          # Test if x[i,j] is 1 (with tolerance for floating point arithmetic).
         if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0.5:
          # print(f'Field {i} Crop {j}.' +
          # f' Priority: {priority[i][j]}' + f' Area: {field_area[i]}' + f' From limit: {crop_limit[j]}' )
         # result['f'] = i;
         # result['c'] = j
         # result['p'] = priority[i][j]
         # result['a'] = field_area[i]
         # result_arr.append(result)
            result_arr.append({'f':i, 'c':j, 'p':priority[i][j],'a':field_area[i]})
  else:
    print('Task doedent have decision.')
 
  # Save the file
  jsondata['result'] = result_arr  
  jsonString = json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4)  
  #print(jsonString) 
  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/response.json', 'w') as outfile:
   outfile.write(jsonString)
  print('File saved.')
```

Tell me what could be the reason?

Im tryed change data and constraints, algorythm distributes crops to fields, but does not pay attention to the limitation (total for crop)

Answer (score 0):

```py
  for j in range(num_crops):
    for i in range(num_fields):
      solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j]] *  field_area[i]) <= crop_limit[j])
```

is suspicious. One inequality per `i` ? No sum over i ?